# I am facing ClassNotFoundException when I try to implement spring boot app as AWS lambda through serverless architecture

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, serverless, java-11

I've tried everything like maven shade plugin, and it is also generating the jar file properly, the only thing I am suspecting is it is packaging application classes into BOOT-INF/classes folder, so can that be an issue? if yes then what's the way to resolve it?

I am trying to implement this with Java 11

START RequestId: 38c9bbd7-c7f1-4779-9486-c19c22528fc4 Version: $LATEST                                                                                                  Class not found: com.application.lambda.LambdaMethodHandler: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException                                                                  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.application.lambda.LambdaMethodHandler. Current classpath: file:/var/task/